# can't install python pacakges

Tags: python, package

I was installing the package "transformers" and its dependencies.

```
pip install transfomers
Collecting transformers
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/87/ef312eef26f5cecd8b17ae9654cdd8d1fae1eb6dbd87257d6d73c128a4d0/transformers-4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.8MB 726kB/s
Collecting regex!=2019.12.17 (from transformers)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/3f/40c8db23e022ccc9eb9fc0f39202af49c8614b22990b2e7129c2543f2da5/regex-2020.11.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (269kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 3.3MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.27 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers) (4.36.1)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers) (3.0.12)
Collecting sacremoses (from transformers)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/34/09d19aff26edcc8eb2a01bed8e98f13a1537005d31e95233fd48216eed10/sacremoses-0.0.43.tar.gz (883kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 890kB 3.2MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers) (0.23)
Collecting numpy>=1.17 (from transformers)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/8f/68b72c57e59591925432f4615309732d5fc5ec0bb0890540e2aa1557172f/numpy-1.20.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (13.6MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 13.6MB 2.2MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers) (19.2)
Collecting tokenizers<0.11,>=0.10.1 (from transformers)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/3a/261b99d6815f6afdd2d35b6420d524305daa17bf430c420dca0115bd1c6c/tokenizers-0.10.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB ...
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sacremoses->transformers) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sacremoses->transformers) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sacremoses->transformers) (0.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->transformers) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from packaging->transformers) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from zipp>=0.5->importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->transformers) (7.2.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: sacremoses
  Building wheel for sacremoses (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for sacremoses: filename=sacremoses-0.0.43-cp37-none-any.whl size=893262 sha256=ff8d68661e9c56c1a7509788a1dfe33e8ccb54968ab9959f01dc364ef08e48a8
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\DSP\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\29\3c\fd\7ce5c3f0666dab31a50123635e6fb5e19ceb42ce38d4e58f45
Successfully built sacremoses
```

However, suddenly the following error appeared:

```
ERROR: Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3012, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2806, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3003, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2806, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 517, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 110, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 49, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2727, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3014, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3023, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3005, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1419, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1607, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\google_pasta-0.1.7.dist-info\\METADATA'
Installing collected packages: regex, sacremoses, numpy, tokenizers, transformers
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.16.5
    Uninstalling numpy-1.16.5:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\compat\\py3k.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.


C:\Users\DSP>pip install regex
Requirement already satisfied: regex in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2020.11.13)
ERROR: Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3012, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2806, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3003, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2806, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 517, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 110, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 49, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2727, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3014, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3023, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3005, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1419, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1607, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\google_pasta-0.1.7.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

Now, even whenever I want to install any packages, the same error appears.
Also, when I want to install the packages "tokenizers", this is what happens:

```
pip install tekenizers
Collecting tekenizers
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tekenizers (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tekenizerspip install tekenizers
Collecting tekenizers
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tekenizers (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tekenizers
```

How should I handle this problem? It seems that the package "transformers" has not been installed either.

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\google_pasta-0.1.7.dist-info\\METADATA'` - thats needs to solve. Try reinstalling packages and anaconda.

Comment: I see a bunch of different problems here, including a permission problem (upgrading numpy failed because you didn't have the necessary permissions to remove the old version); a missing metadata file for google_pasta; also, you're trying to install `tekenizers` instead of `tokenizers`

Answer (score 3):

Such errors can be caused by a package being installed by one provider (say, `conda`) but subsequently removed by `pip`. Whereas `pip` may uninstall it, it may not fully remove all associated metadata files that `conda` additionally maintains, making `conda` think the package exists, but in a broken format (and vice versa for using conda to remove pip-installed packages).

To get around this, manually remove any remaining package-specific files from your disk for any packages giving you this error, e.g. `rm -r c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\google_pasta-*` in a Unix-like shell.